# Attribute decoration and reflection in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Is their anyway to add decoration to properties in objective-c, that can be discovered during run-time using reflection? I would like to define the following class

```
@interface ABC{}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * s1;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * s2;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * s3;
```

I would like to add some kind of attribute for the properties s1 and s2, so I can discover these properties during run-time and perform some operation, which is not applicable to s3.
So something like

[Run-Time_Discover]
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * s1;

I know that Tnterface builder, uses IBOutlet for discovering properties. Can I discover properties defined by some such macro during run-time?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an object implements a method (and remember, properties are just methods) like this:

`[theObject respondsToSelector:@selector(s3)];`

No need for annotations here.

Comment: Heh. Your edit had some spelling and grammatical issues, so I'm not sure how much it helped. I fixed things up to be a bit more explanatory.